# Display Image in View not Working in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, oop

**Controller code for store image**

```
$data = new Data;

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $fileName = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->image->storeAs('/images', $fileName);
    $data->image = $fileName;
    $data->save();
}
```

**Blade**

```
<td>
    <img height="100" width="200" src="images/{{ $item['image'] ? $item->image : 'http://placehold.it/400x400' }} " alt="">
</td>
```

**Browser Console**
[image]

Comment: is your images directory inside public folder?

Comment: yes, storage/images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace src like below

src="{{asset('storage'}}/images/{{ $item['image'] ? $item->image :'http://placehold.it/400x400' }} "

Comment: Just add the storage path before your image link

Comment: Still not got the image

Comment: Add third parameter here $request->image->storeAs('/images', $fileName, 'public');